# node.js read binary data using Ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax, binary

In BE server, I send binarystring to FE server. Binarystring is in responseText.

```
//So. I do this.\
xhr2.open('GET', url, true);
xhr2.onload = function() 
{
    routeResponse = Buffer.from(xhr2.responseText, 'binary');

    //init
    Buf = '';

    //byte by byte output
    for (let i = 0; i < routeResponse.length; i++) {
        Buf += routeResponse.readUInt8(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        Buf += ' ';
    }
    console.log(Buf);
}
```

But It's different binary data in log and original cgi file.

[left : console.log(Buf) / Right : Hexadecimal value in original file. ex) getRoute.cgi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWoqp.png)

Oddly, only certain values ​​are output as 'FD'. Actual data is '8B', '8C' and so on.

cgi file fomat : binary / Little Endian.

Why certain data are replaced to 'FD'
Please answer for me.

thank you.

Comment: Only data after 127 (signed char) get affected. Idk but you should look at signed/unsigned and how you construct your buffer before to send it.

Comment: When output to readInt8 instead of readUInt8, that 'FD' value changed to '-3'.

How does print '-3'..? I don't understand... Where did it all go wrong?

Comment: Just send `8C` only from server and read it from client. Look at binary data you get and the differences, try multiple things until you get it.